# Calculate edge probability of a graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

I wonder what is the edge probability $p$ for which a random graph with $n = 5000$ nodes has the largest expected diameter?

How can I calculate that?

Is there someone who can help me? This would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disconnected graph has infinite diameter, so $p=0$ will work.